# Using the Joomla 2.5 login script

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, joomla2.5

So I'm trying to login a user to Joomla through an AJAX call. Is there a login script already written that I can just pass username and password variables? Pretty much I am just looking to use the below script and want to just find the correct url to use. Is this possible?

```
$('body').delegate('#login', 'click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $username = $('#username').val();
    $password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ineedthisurl.php',
        data: {username: $username, password: $password},
        success: function(responseData){
            window.location = $url;
        },
        error: function(responseData){
            console.log('login script error');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the relevant script in:

```
/components/com_users/controllers/users.php
```

took a bit of playing around with but I got it working.